# ServiceNow REST API and PowerBI

Tags: powershell, api, rest, powerbi, servicenow

Is there a way that I can get data from service now API from PowerBI directly? I have the following powershell code

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$body = @{
env = "https://companyqa.service-now.com/"
username = "username"
password = "password"
client_id = "client_id"
client_secret = "client_secret"
grant_type = "password"
}

$gettoken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "$($body.env)oauth_token.do?grant_type=password&client_id=$($body.client_id)&client_secret=$($body.client_secret)&username=$($body.username)&password=$($body.password)" -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
$token = $gettoken.access_token
echo $token
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $token”}
$Type = "application/json"
$getincidents = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "$($body.env)/api/now/v2/table/incident?sysparm_query=number=NUM111111" -Headers $headers -ContentType $Type
$getincidents.result
```

I am looking for example to replicate the above in PowerBI and get the data directly fed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the PowerBI content back for Service Now to create an initial report, you can then find the logic in PowerBI and customise for your use case.

From the [PowerBI blog on Service Now](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/explore-your-servicenow-data-with-power-bi/) connectivity:

To connect to the content pack, simply provide the URL to your ServiceNow instance, and sign in with your username and password. Once the connection has been made, Power BI will automatically create a dashboard, report, and dataset with data from your ServiceNow account.